# passing variables across functions on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass variables across functions,
something like

```js
function one() {
  var x = 1
}

function two() {
  var y = x + 1;
}

alert(y);
```

Is there a way to do it?

edit:Thanks everyone for being so helpful, but maybe I should have been more specific with my question.

Comment: Please show us how you intend to call the functions. Without calling them, no assignment is done and no value is ever created.

Comment: Also please explain why you want/need to do this? Having function accept arguments and return values is a much better design.

Answer (score 2):

You current way has x and y in the scope of the function, which means the other function doesnt know it exists. Also, its good practice to name functions according to what they do. 3 straightforward ways to do this.

1. Global
2. Params
3. Inline

---

1. Set two variables outside of the functions scope that any function can reach.

```js
var x, y;

function assignOne() {
   x = 1;
}

function addOne() {
  y = x + 1;
}

assignOne();
addOne();
console.log(y);
```

2. Pass in a parameter to to the function and return values.

```js
function one() {
   return 1;
}

function addOneTo(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

const y = addOneTo(one());
console.log(y);
```

3. Perform functions inline

```js
var x = null;

function one() {
   x = 1;
}

function two() {
  return x + 1;
}

one();
const y = two();
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hoist the scope, by extracting the variable declaration to outside of the functions. That is to say, define `x` and `y` outside of the functions. Note that you can still update their *values* from *within* the functions. However, don't forget that you'll actually need to invoke both functions as well!

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var x, y;

function one() {
   x = 1;
}

function two() {
  y = x + 1;
}

one();
two();
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get variable declared in one method, return it

```js
  function one(){
        var x = 1;
        return x;
    }
    
    function two() {
      var x = one();
      var y = x + 1;
      return y;
    }
alert(two());
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to have **shared state** between both functions instead of passing arguments. So, an object oriented pattern seems to be appropriate.

```js
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 1;
  }
  one() {
    return this.x;
  }
  two() {
    return this.x + 1;
  }
}

const t = new Thing();
console.log(t.one());
console.log(t.two());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share variables between functions but don't want to declare them in global scope, you can use a closure like this:

```
(function() {
  var x, y;

  function one() {
    var x = 1
  }

  function two() {
    var y = x + 1;
  }
  one();
  two();
  alert(y);
})();
```